# How to read a configuration file in Java

Tags: java, configuration-files

I am doing a project to build `thread pooled web server`, in which I have to set

- the port number on which server listens.
- How many threads are there in thread pool
- Absolute Path of the root directory, and so many points.

One way is to hard code all these variables in the code, that I did. But professionally it is not good.

Now, I want to make one configuration file, in which I put all these data, and at the run time my code fetches these.

How can I make configuration file for the above task ?

Answer (score 33):

**app.config**

```
app.name=Properties Sample Code
app.version=1.09
```

---

**Source code:**

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
String fileName = "app.config";
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
    prop.load(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ... // FileNotFoundException catch is optional and can be collapsed
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ...
}
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("app.name"));
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("app.version"));
```

---

**Output:**

```
Properties Sample Code
1.09
```

Comment: Wher is stored app.config... ?

Comment: Next to the executable file, however, you can put it anywhere and enter its full address.

Comment: can that file be dynamically used? Such as changing the values from externally

Answer (score 14):

It depends.

Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), take a look at [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html), take a look at [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) and maybe even [Java API for XML Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) and [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/TOC.html)

And if none of those meet your particular needs, you could even look at using some kind of [Database](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Answer (score 14):

Create a configuration file and put your entries there.

```
SERVER_PORT=10000     
THREAD_POOL_COUNT=3     
ROOT_DIR=/home/
```

You can load this file using `Properties.load(fileName)` and retrieved values you `get(key)`;

Comment: you can just set value ROOT_DIR=logs/ assuming the project path is your classpath. Your logs will be placed in `your project path/ROOT_DIR`

Comment: As my project name is `WebServer`, m, where can I put log , then ?

Comment: It is enough that you create a folder named `logs` in your project directory and put an entry in your conf file as  `ROOT_DIR=logs`.

Comment: It works fine to set log file location, but I cannot solve problem to set location of server.properties. How can I set this in my java code ?

Comment: Right now I am using these statements, `File f = new File("C://Users//jhamb//Desktop//WebServer//src//main//resources//server.properties");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
props.load(is);` How can I change the server.properties path in this , so that there is no need to set always in different machines.

Comment: Yes, my code is in src-->main-->java-->XXX-->YYY-->ZZZ-->[MY CODE IS HERE]

Comment: Assuming that you are running your code from src, `File file = new File("main"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator"+"server.properties)`

Comment: Why dont you keep your resources out of src?? In that case you can directly access resources/server.properties.

Comment: I didn't understand, Maven has its own File system, and I think all the resources must be put in the resources, conventionally.

Comment: DO you know any method , just like `log4j` has to load log properties, just `// Configure Log4J
PropertyConfigurator.configure(Main.class.getClassLoader()
.getResource("log4j.properties"));`

Comment: I solved this, `File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "server.properties");` works for me. :) :)

Comment: Could you provide explain what you understand by fileName in your answer? It's logical to me to put actual String with the name of the file in such variable - but I see I have to use Reader/InputStream here.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - passing the filename to `Properties.load` won't work - it needs an `InputStream` or a `Reader`, not a `String`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html